# How i can create hexagon shape with rectangle in background?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I create example like it was on picture(run code snipped in full screen), but i ask if its better way to do this. If i zoom webpage i see borders of shapes, so can i create hexagon in one object and add rectangle in background.

Thanks for the advice !
Example
[image]

```css
.arrow-left {
    margin-top: 40px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 160px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 160px solid transparent;
    border-right:80px solid white;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.backwhite{
    margin-top: 40px;
    width: 50%;
    height:320px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color:#000000;
    vertical-align: top;

}

.arrow-left_yellow {

    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 160px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 160px solid transparent;
    border-right:80px solid #FFAA00;
    float:right;

}
.arrow-right_yellow {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 200px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 200px solid transparent;
    border-left: 100px solid #FFAA00;

}
.cube {
    width: 250px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #FFAA00;
}

.backwhite, .arrow-left,.arrow-left_yellow ,.arrow-right_yellow,.cube{
    display: inline-block;
}

.backwhite-text{
    float:left;
    width: 80%;
}

.backwhite-text >h1{
    color:#000000;
    text-align: center;
}
.backwhite-text>p{
   color:#000000;
}



.trapezoid {
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 40px 0px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 320px;
    background-color: #FFAA00;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
.trapezoid::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -40px;
    border-top: 40px solid transparent;
    border-left: 0 px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid #FFAA00;
    border-bottom: 111px solid #FFAA00;
}
.trapezoid::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -40px;
    border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
    border-left: 0px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid #FFAA00;
    border-top: 111px solid #FFAA00;
}


#single-project{
    padding-top: 310px;
}
```

```html
<div id="single-project">
 <div class="arrow-left"></div><div class="backwhite"> <div class="backwhite-text"><h1>H1 H1 H1 H1</h1><p>TextText</p></div><div class="arrow-left_yellow"></div></div><div class="trapezoid"></div><div class="cube"></div><div class="arrow-right_yellow"></div>


</div>
```

Comment: here is a guide on how to create shapes with CSS: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: Thanks, but i need white rectangle in background of hexagon, what is happen with z-index. Answer below. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can create a hexagon object and add rectangle in the background. Use the z-index property. Check this article: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

Comment: Great, i did it. Its much better for look and to use with image. Thanks

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to provide the actual information here and not just a link. [Link-only answers are not considered good answers and will probably be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).